# .NET MAUI - DatePicker Selection in Does Not Update Grid in CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, datepicker, maui

I am working on an application that utilizes the [NHL API](https://github.com/dword4/nhlapi). I have a page that displays the schedule. By default, it loads the current day's games. I have a DatePicker in the `'CollectionView.Header'`, then a Grid within the `ScheduleTemplate` to display the data. If I select a new date in the DatePicker, it fires off the Property `"get"` process and loads the latest data into my `"ObservableGames"` List as expected, but the Grid clears completely and I just have a DatePicker left with an empty screen.

SchedulePage.xaml View:

```
<RefreshView Command="{Binding UpdateScheduleCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
    <CollectionView Margin="20"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableGames}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ScheduleTemplate}"
                SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.Header>
            <Grid>
                <DatePicker Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" Date="{Binding SelectedDatePickerDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Grid>
        </CollectionView.Header>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

App.xaml DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ScheduleTemplate">
    <Grid Padding="8" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions=".1*,.5*,.2*,.2*">
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding AwayTeamLogo, Mode=TwoWay}" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AwayAbbreviatedName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding AwayGoals, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding GameStatusString, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding HomeTeamLogo, Mode=TwoWay}" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding HomeAbbreviatedName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding HomeGoals, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ScheduleViewModel}}, Path=GameTapped}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

ViewModel:

```
class ScheduleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime? _selectedDatePickerDate;
    bool isRefreshing;


    public ObservableCollection<Game> ObservableGames { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DatePickerDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentScheduleDate { get; set; }
    public Command<Game> GameTapped { get; }
    public Command<DateTime?> DatePickerTapped { get; }
    public ICommand UpdateScheduleCommand => new Command(async () => await SetScheduleDataAsync());

    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get
        {
            return isRefreshing;
        }
        set
        {
            isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime? SelectedDatePickerDate
    {
        get => _selectedDatePickerDate;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedDatePickerDate, value);
            OnDatePickerSelected(value);
        }
    }


    public ScheduleViewModel()
    {
        ObservableGames = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
        GameTapped = new Command<Game>(OnGameSelected);
        DatePickerTapped = new Command<DateTime?>(OnDatePickerSelected);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObservableGames));
        DatePickerDate = DateTime.Today;
        SetScheduleDataAsync();
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    async void OnGameSelected(Game game)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"scheduledetails?gameLink={game.link}");
    }

    private void OnDatePickerSelected(DateTime? gameDate)
    {
        if (null != gameDate)
        {
            DatePickerDate = gameDate.Value;
            SetScheduleDataAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task SetScheduleDataAsync()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;

        if (DatePickerDate != CurrentScheduleDate)
        {
            ObservableGames.Clear();
            ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule = ScheduleData.GetSchedule(-1, DatePickerDate, null, string.Empty);

            try
            {
                if ((null != ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule) && (null != ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule.dates) && (ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule.dates.Count > 0)
                        && (null != ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule.dates[0]) && (ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule.dates[0].games.Count > 0))
                {
                    ObservableGames = new ObservableCollection<Game>(ScheduleData.LeagueSchedule.dates[0].games);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ObservableGames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if ((null != ObservableGames[i]) && (null != ObservableGames[i].status) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObservableGames[i].status.detailedState)))
                        {
                            switch (ObservableGames[i].status.detailedState.ToLower())
                            {
                                case "final":
                                    ObservableGames[i].AwayGoals = ObservableGames[i].teams.away.score;
                                    ObservableGames[i].HomeGoals = ObservableGames[i].teams.home.score;
                                    ObservableGames[i].GameStatusString = ObservableGames[i].status.detailedState;
                                    break;
                                case "in progress":
                                    LiveGame liveGame = GameData.GetLiveGame(ObservableGames[i].link);

                                    if (null != liveGame)
                                    {
                                        ObservableGames[i].AwayGoals = liveGame.liveData.linescore.teams.away.goals;
                                        ObservableGames[i].HomeGoals = liveGame.liveData.linescore.teams.home.goals;
                                        ObservableGames[i].GameStatusString = liveGame.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodTimeRemaining + " " + liveGame.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodOrdinal;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "postponed":
                                    ObservableGames[i].GameStatusString = "Postponed";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ObservableGames[i].GameStatusString = ObservableGames[i].gameDate.ToLocalTime().ToShortTimeString();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                CurrentScheduleDate = DatePickerDate;
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using multiple Views, moved logic around and updated access modifiers. I have even debugged and the ObservableGames object does get updated with the new set of games based on the DatePicker Selection... . I just don't see it in the Grid.

Comment: you are replacing `ObservableGames` with a **new instance**, which breaks the binding.  Either add items to the existing instance, or call `PropertyChanged` in the setter to update the UI when a new instance is assigned

Comment: UGH, that was it, thank you! I modified the ViewModel to add to the existing instance.